# How can I check numbered lists that matches current n value?

Tags: python, list, loops

For example, I have these three lists:

```
r0 = ['X', 'O', 'O'] 
r1 = ['X', 'X', 'O']
r2 = ['X', '.', 'O']
```

And I want to use a loop like this one:

```
n = 0    
while n < 3:
    if r0[n] == r1[n] == r2[n] == "X":
        result = "X"
        break
    elif rn[0] == rn[1] == rn[2] == "O":
        result = "O"
        break
```

What I want `rn` to be is `r0` when `n == 0`, `r1` when `n == 1` and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want:

```
for n, rn in enumerate((r0, r1, r2)):
```

Generally, I think it would be better to change your structure to a list of lists:

```
r = [['X', 'O', 'O'],
     ['X', 'X', 'O'],
     ['X', '.', 'O']]
```

Then your loop is:

```
for n, rn in enumerate(r):
```

Comment: Huh, TIL about enumerate. I've always done `for n in range(len(r)): do_stuff_with(r[n])`

Comment: @alecbenzer `range(len(r))` is rarely the right thing to do, there's usually a `zip` or `enumerate` or something from `itertools` to do the job more neatly!

Comment: If I were to use this, how would I be able to reference a value from each of the lists? I've tried things like `r[0[0]]` but it doesn't work. Thank you for your quick and informative response!

Comment: @Bassmaster you want `r[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
r = [r0, r1, r2]
for n, rn in enumerate(r):
    if r0[n] == 'X' and r1[n] == 'X' and r2[n] == 'X':
        result = 'X'
        break
    elif rn[0] == 'O' and rn[1] == 'O' and rn[2] == 'O':
        result = 'O'
        break
```

Perhaps more neatly:

```
rows = [['X', 'O', 'O'],
        ['X', 'X', 'O'],
        ['X', '.', 'O']]

for n, row in enumerate(rows):
    if all(row[n] == 'X' for row in rows):  # shadowing 'row' here, not sure what else you might call it
        result = 'X'
        break
    elif all(r == 'O' for r in row):
        result = 'O'
        break
```